Find if a set of lists of 2 values are the result of the possible combination of a n-value list
I have used itertools to find all possible 2-element combination (without repetition) from a set of 10 elements to which I have applied some filtering to reduce the 2-element combination based on given condition
For simplicity suppose the code below: the 10 elements are the number 1 to 10. The code I have used is following:
import numpy as np

M = np.array(np.transpose(np.loadtxt('C:\\py\\10.csv')))

n=2

from itertools import combinations

combos = list(filter(lambda e:   ((e[0]+e[1]) > 14 ) , combinations(M, n)))

print (combos) 

The output will then be
[(5.0, 10.0), (6.0, 9.0), (6.0, 10.0), (7.0, 8.0), (7.0, 9.0), (7.0, 10.0), (8.0, 9.0), (8.0, 10.0), (9.0, 10.0)]

What I am now trying to achieve, programmatically, is to compress the above results into a n-element list that would have generated it.
For example I can say (6.0, 9.0), (6.0, 10.0), (9.0, 10.0) are the two element combination of a list of 3 elements (6,9,10)
I can also say (7.0, 8.0), (7.0, 9.0), (7.0, 10.0), (8.0, 9.0), (8.0, 10.0), (9.0, 10.0) are the two element combination of a list of 4 elements (7,8,9,10)
I can also say that the (5.0, 10.0) pair it is not the result of the combination of a sublist of the 10 numbers
If anyone came across this problem I'd like to know how this could be achieved

There are two problems here. The first one is flattening the list, the second one is to get unique numbers from the list.
There are multiple ways of achieving this. One is just iterating through the nested structure and adding values to a set:
numbers = set()
for combo in combos:
    for value in combo:
        numbers.add(value)

or  in a one liner:
numbers = {value for combo in combos for value in combo}

